# navigator.network.connection.type returns null instead of Connection.NONE

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, connection

For some reason the Phonegap connection API returns `null`

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
    alert(networkState);
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    document.getElementById('connections').innerHTML = states[networkState];
}
```

I run this function from the `onDeviceReady` function which is called when the device is running.

When everything is turned off I get `null`. Shouldn't I get the `Connection.NONE` back instead of a `null`? It's really annoying since I can't check whether the phone has connection or not. It works fine when Wifi is turned on though.

Comment: Hey, I've read the code it shouldn't ever return null. What is your reproduction scenario for this bug? I've put my phone into airplane mode and it returns "none" correctly. Are you making sure to wait for the "deviceready" event before you make a call to checkConnection()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the PhoneGap discussion group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/phonegap/navigator.network.connection.type/phonegap/oAggxryQzrw/hE8uhwN3ONgJ

If you're using 1.6.0, you need to update res/xml/plugins.xml from

```
<plugin name="Network Status" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
```

to be:

```
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
```

(You need to remove the space in "Network Status")

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using PhoneGap 1.4.1 and Sencha Touch 1.1.1. on Android 2.3.5 (tested with HTC Desire S).
It seems that the "navigator.network.connection.type" statement does effectively return 'null' with Phonegap 1.4.1, even if called after 'deviceready' event has been fired (confirmed after checking the source code). However it perfectly works with Cordova (ex-PhoneGap) 1.5.0. So I suggest to upgrade asap :-)

Eric.

Answer (score 1):

For the cordova version prior to 1.6 you need to use:

```
<plugin name="Network Status" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
```

Instead of:

```
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
```

Please change the plugin name to "Network Status" with space!

Comment: Erm, [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10176489/1110760) answer from april the 16th says different.

Comment: the other way around <plugin name="Network Status" value="org.apache.cordova.network.Network" /> link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

Answer (score 1):

There is another change when going from pre 2.3.0 to post 2.3.0.

> Before Cordova 2.3.0, the Connection object existed at:
>   navigator.network.connection.
>
> To match the spec, this was changed to navigator.connection in 2.3.0.
>
> navigator.network.connection still exists, but is now deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future release.

[2.7.0 docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html)

So change this

```
 var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
```

To This

```
 var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
```

Basically remove the network from your Javascript.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Might be useful for people using the latest version of Cordova!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
```

Instead of:

```
var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
```